# Chicago O’Hare - Two Towers?

Tags: airport, airport-design, airport-operations

Why does ORD have two towers? I flew in there for a connecting flight this last weekend and saw two towers standing, one obviously larger than the other.

Comment: Apparently there are four. see https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27134/what-is-the-division-of-tasks-among-the-control-towers-at-chicago-ohare-airport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, a lot of airports, especially ones that are Class B (very busy), will have multiple control towers. Most of the time, there is a single operational control tower focused on departures/arrivals into the airport environment with one or multiple smaller ground control towers focused on ground movement area coordination. I hope this helps!