# Why does the Las Vegas Airport have three control towers?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport-design

Why does the Las Vegas Airport have three control towers? I just noticed, and I find it a little weird. There should only be one... Does anybody know details on how this came about? And how they work like that?

[image]

EDIT: Not a duplicate, the question is specific to Las Vegas Airport, the other question is about another airport.

Comment: From the [Airport Diagram](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1712/pdf/00662AD.PDF), I only see a single control tower, located just west of Terminal 3.  Where do you think the others are?  Please provide references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does having multiple ATC towers affect airport operations?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-does-having-multiple-atc-towers-affect-airport-operations)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: I've added an image from Google Earth that shows the three towers that I believe you're referring to.

Comment: Relevant:  https://www.reviewjournal.com/local/local-las-vegas/old-mccarran-airport-tower-meets-a-1-99m-demise/

Old tower is scheduled to be demolished.  The other "tower" is likely ramp/ground control.

Comment: @GregHewgill This question is about the Las Vegas Airport. The other question is about Schiphol airport. Please also note, that Las Vegas has three towers, which is very unusual, Schiphol has two. Please read the question more carefully before flagging a question. This causes at least another edit for me for an absolutely valid question, that I already had research before posting, and that already required three edits in one hour...

Comment: @mike Last time I counted (it was today) Schiphol had five towers.

Comment: @DeltaLima Really? Where are they all? I'm only aware of "the tower" and the one by the polderbaan...

Comment: There are two operational towers at Schiphol (the main tower and tower west at the polderbaan). Then the former control tower next to the main tower and the tower at gate D. Finally the very old tower (1952) at Schiphol east which now is a restaurant/flight simulator facility, across the road from the ATC centre building.

Comment: You have to be redundant for safety reasons :-)

Comment: There are three tower structures, but only one is the control tower

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of those is the old tower, built in 1983, and scheduled for demolition.
(in the bottom left of the picture)

The location and height of the old tower created blind spots, which were covered by the much shorter ground control tower attached to the D Gates. (upper right of the picture)

The new tower is in a better location, and tall enough that it doesn't have blind spots.  I couldn't find a reference to if the D-Gate mini-tower will continue, or be demolished.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: https://www.reviewjournal.com/local/local-las-vegas/old-mccarran-airport-tower-meets-a-1-99m-demise/

Answer (score 0):

airports which have existed for many years often have a succession of control towers which were built in each revision of the airport, and in some cases the older ones are allowed to stand. I look for them each time I land at an unfamiliar airport- the more towers, the older the airport, and the more history there is in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

Previous commenters are correct that old towers can stay around well after a new one is put up. Look at IAD. I'd also add that sometimes there are ramp towers at airports and they can look like regular air traffic control towers.

Answer (score 0):

The mini tower is the East Ramp Control tower, used to park planes at assigned gates. There is another Ramp Control Tower situated on the south end of the terminal 1 garage that monitors the west airfield.

Comment: Can you expand on that and provide some pictures please?